# Fluent-bit: Extract two or more line types from a single log file into separate tags / outputs

Tags: filtering, fluent-bit, fluent-bit-rewrite-tag

## **Overall goal**

I have a huge application specific log-file, easily per-line-parsable, with two (or more) types of log lines I would like to tail and extract with fluent-bit for further processing in a time series database / elastic / etc.

1. First category of interest are "RECEIVED" lines which indicate incoming requests:

```
    2023-03-25 00:33:17 <  43084:X@540435747125056> RECEIVED /req:10.45.3.24(10.45.3.24):user9458:service8457:
```

2. Second category of interest are "DURATION" lines which indicate that we answered with a response to the request:

```
    2023-03-25 00:33:17 <  43084:X@540435747125056> DURATION TO RESPONSE  15.178 ms::user9458:service8457:
```

The majority of lines like the following is of no interest for further processing at this point in time and shall be omitted:

```
    2023-03-25 00:33:17 <  43084:X@540435747125056> <X:   > request_details_of_no_interest
```

## **Expected result**

For the start I just would like to dump the output

- into separate files named as the tag of the line category
- all of those extraction files should be written in the same subdirectory /opt/app/logs/extracted

So, I would expect some result like the following for the differing example lines:

1. In file named "hostname.my_incoming":

```
incoming: [1679700797.000000000, {"ip":"10.45.3.24","user":"user9458","service":"service8457"}]
```

2. In file named "hostname.my_done":

```
done: [1679700797.000000000, {"duration_ms":"15.178","user":"user9458","service":"service8457"}]
```

Ideally we achieve this in a stacked approach, by handling the two (or more) line types with own and simple regular expressions and with separate tags each.

**Additional requirement**
The tailed log file /opt/app/logs/http.log is being rotated on a daily basis by moving it to sub-folder /opt/app/logs/archived and then gzip compressing it while a new http.log is generated.

## **My current failed status**

So far, I indeed achieved to output into two output files, one named "hostname.my_done" as expected but unfortunately for second (or hird, etc.) I do not succeed in rewriting the tag to "hostname.my_incoming". Instead the second extraction is written to file named "market1.app", the initial tag used in my configuration.
All in all, this indicates that I do not yet understand well enough how fluent-bit is working altogether :-)

**Please find my patterns.conf:**

```
[PARSER]
    Name    my_basic
    Format  regex
    Regex   ^(?<time>\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+)\ (?<message>.*)$
    Time_Key    time
    Time_Format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

[PARSER]
    Name    my_incoming
    Format  regex
    Regex   ^.*\((?<ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\):(?<user>[^:]+):(?<service>[^:]+):.*$

[PARSER]
    Name    my_done
    Format  regex
    Regex   ^.*DURATION\ TO\ RESPONSE\s+(?<duration>[\d\.]+)\ ms:.*:(?<user>[^:]+):(?<service>[^:]+):.*$
```

**and the relevant sections of the fluent-bit.conf:**

```
[INPUT]
    name tail
    path /opt/app/logs/http.log*
    Tag  market1.app
    Parser my_basic
    DB /opt/app/logs/file_status.db
    Refresh_Interval 10

# Grep only the lines of interest
[FILTER]
    name grep
    match *
    regex message RECEIVED|DURATION\ TO\ RESPONSE

# Parse first type of log lines
[FILTER]
    Name Parser
    match *app
    Key_Name message
    Parser my_incoming

# Rewrite the tag of all non-matching lines of the previous parsing
[FILTER]
    Name rewrite_tag
    Match *.app
    Rule $message RECEIVED ${HOSTNAME}.my_done false
    Emitter_Name my_done

# Parse the second type of log lines with the rewritten tag name "my_done"
[FILTER]
    Name Parser
    match *my_done
    Key_Name message
    Parser my_done

# HERE I FAIL: I cannot rewrite the tag for the first type of log lines / records
#[FILTER]
#    Name rewrite_tag
#    match *app
#    Rule $ip ^.*$ ${HOSTNAME}.my_incoming false
#    Emitter_Name my_incoming

[OUTPUT]
    name  file
    match *
    path /opt/app/logs/extracted
```